# Displaying property object instead of value in Flask template

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, flask, cas

In my Python (3.5) Flask project, I am using the [CAS client](https://github.com/cameronbwhite/Flask-CAS)  for authentication and everything works fine. Once the authentication is done, I want to display the username in my output page. So I use the following code

*`__init__.py`*:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cas import CAS
from flask_cas import login_required
# ...

APP = Flask(__name__)
cas = CAS(APP)
# ...

def list_page()
     return render_template("list.html", name=cas.username)

@app.route('/admin/')
@login_required
def admin_page()
    return list_page();
```

*`list.html`*:

```
...
<H2> Hi {{name}} </h2>
...
```

At the output page I am seeing

```
Hi <property object at 0x7fb37dfe6958>
```

Comment: We need to see the definition of the `cas` variable for this to be answerable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have updated the code to include the instantiation part.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce the issue; the `cas.username` attribute *will* return a string, not `<property object at 0xhexaddress>`.

Comment: Put differently, are you *sure* you didn't accidentally use `name=CAS.username` instead of `name=cas.username`? Or, somewhere else in your code, assigned something else to the name `cas`?

Comment: Thanks Martijn, your last message was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to pinpoint exactly what the problem is without knowing what your `cas` variable is, in `__init__.py`. However I suspect the error you have might be because `cas` is a class, rather than an instance of that class.

To show you what I mean:

```
>>> class MyCAS:
...    @property
...    def name(self):
...        return 'Monjur'
...
>>> MyCAS.name
<property object at 0x109cf1cc8>
>>> MyCAS().name
'Monjur'
```

In the first case, I have not instantiated the class (no parenthesis), so the return value is the property object.
In the second case (with parenthesis), I see the actual name of the instance.

If your `cas` object is indeed supposed to be an object instantiated from a class (e.g. `flask.ext.cas.CAS`), make sure you create it like this:

```
from flask.ext.cas import CAS
cas = CAS() # With parenthesis :)
```

and not like this:

```
from flask.ext.cas import CAS
cas = CAS  # No parenthesis :(
```

Comment: I will try the approach and will let you know.

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan I saw your latest edit, and as the comments suggest, you are probably re-assigning `cas` to something else. Did you get to check whether this variable was a class vs. an instance when inside `list_page()`?